# Using jQuery to calculate width of overflow text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some divs which contain various amounts of text inside a container which has a fixed width. To stop the text from overflowing outside the container, I am using the following CSS:

```
overflow:hidden;
text-overflow:ellipsis;
white-space:nowrap;
```

Is there any way I can calculate the width of the text as it would be if it was not cut off?
Using the following code only provides me with the width after it has been trimmed.

```
$('.boxText').width();
```

Just to clarify - I *am* talking about the width. **Not** the character length.

Comment: what does your html look like? I think it the text is contained within a p for example, it might be possible to calculate the width of the p

Comment: It's currently within a div tag, but I'll see if making it a `p` tag helps!

Comment: try the p tag inside the div tag. It might be more complicated than I thought but hope this helps http://jsfiddle.net/XD4kD/

Comment: Why do you need to calculate the width of the text? It looks like you're trying to overcomplicate this a bit, I might be wrong but is it worth knowing the width of the text?

Comment: @Leo Yes. I'm creating some breadcrumbs which are all a fixed width but if the text is being clipped by the CSS, the width of the breadcrumb will increase to the width of the text on hover.

Comment: Why don't you then set the width to auto?

Comment: Your breadcrumbs/containers...how are they being displayed? Inline, block, inline-block?

Comment: @jesteuvidim Because I need to use that value to do another separate calculation.

Comment: What value do you need to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var divWidthBefore = $('.boxText').width();
$('.boxText').css('width','auto');
var divWidth = $('.boxText').width();
$('.boxText').width(divWidthBefore);
```

Comment: +1 this is the easiest and obvious solution rather than hacking the width of the text

Comment: This does the job partly, however I need to use a CSS transition to change the initial width to the `auto` width, and CSS transitions don't like `auto` values! :(